# Why am I getting: EventError: libraries entries only supported by python27 runtime? when running GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I'm running a local development copy of Google AppEngine PHP SDK v1.8.0, with PHP v5.4.3 and Python v2.7, all under Windows 7 64bit.

I have followed instructions from a number of posts both here and elsewhere in order to register Python with my OS and to properly install the Python PIL module.

The last post I found here [Unable to find the Python PIL library.Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170898/unable-to-find-the-python-pil-library-google-app-engine/4821894#4821894). I have therefore added :

```
libraries:
- name: PIL
  version: 1.1.7
```

to app.yaml.

I now receive the error quoted in the title of this post. If anyone can advise, I would be grateful.

Thankyou.

Comment: I would hazard a guess you runtime in app.yaml is php and not python27

Comment: That's correct. All is as it should be according to the AppEngine docs for setting up the PHP version of the SDK. If I understand you correctly this error is therefore nothing to be concerned about. What I'm trying to test is running a Wordpress instance on Google AppEngine.

I won't worry about it for now (I'm not a practiced developer) and see how it goes.

Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

I think what @Tim was trying to say is that you should change your app.yaml to say "runtime: python27" instead of "runtime: php" since, as the error suggests, the PIL library is only supported by python27, not php.