# PIL cannot be found

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

```
RuntimeError: NotImplementedError('Unable to find the Python Python Imaging Library.  Please view the SDK documentation for details about installing PIL on your system.',).
```

Through google app engine log i am getting this error.
i m trying to upload a image.
i have installed PIL but still its showing cannot find.
i have installed it in

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages.
```

This is the app.yaml

```
application: uniqueappid
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: PIL
  version: 1.1.7
```

Comment: you followed this one https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/installingPIL ?

Comment: Ya i did but it is still showing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the PIL library can not be loaded for **ANY** reason. I am running OSX so the solution for you might be different for you, but maybe describing what I did will help others.

For me the problem was that my Python 2.7.13 for OSX did not ship with a `yaml` library, and requiring the images library failed because of that. Running this fixed the issue for me:

```
sudo pip install pyyaml
```

The total installs I needed to get the images API working locally was the following:

```
sudo pip install Pillow pyyaml
```

The packages need to be installed globally, as they will be used by the API server. Installing the packages locally with `-t` and adding the library directory to `appengine_config.py` **DID NOT WORK**.

In addition to this I needed to have the version fixed as 1.1.7 in my app.yaml even though your Pillow version will not be the same:

```
libraries:
- name: PIL
  version: 1.1.7
```

As mentioned, your problem with loading the library might be different, so here is how I discovered my missing `yaml` dependency:

From the following last callstack line I interpreted that my app engine libraries reside in `/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine`:

```
File "/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 259, in _MakeRealSyncCall
```

By reading the code I figured out that the module which is responsible for detecting if `PIL` is installed is `google.appengine.api.images.images_stub`, so I did the following:

```
cd /Applications/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/
python -c 'from google.appengine.api.images import images_stub'
```

.. which resulted in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
[... callstack omitted ...]
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

This allowed me to figure out that the import was failing because of the missing `yaml` module.